# tun.ko for Samsung Intercept/Stock Froyo

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-intercept, openvpn

I have a Samsung Intercept, running the VM stock image of Froyo. I'm trying to get OpenVpn running on it. The phone is rooted, and I have OpenVpn and the gui from the marketplace running on it, and running openvpn from the command line shows its connecting up, authenticating, but there IS no tun.ko. The several I've found on the net that *claim* to work on an Intercept but *don't*.. When trying to insmod all of these I get an error indicating kernel module was built for an "ARMv7" vs "ARMv6".. Anyone have an tun.ko for an Intercept OR alternatively a link to a howto on building Android kernels/kernel modules on Linux? I'm quite familiar with how to do that on Linux, but clueless on doing a crossplatform build on Linux..

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

CyanogenMod 6 is Froyo, and ships with OpenVPN support for ARMv6 phones, such as my HTC Magic.

If nothing else you can unpack the update.zip they supply, find the tun.ko driver, and push it to your phone via adb.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I downloaded the CyanogenMod 6 package (update-cm-6.10 DS-signed.zip) that was offered for the HTC Magic. Unpacked and searched the whole tree and found no tun.ko anywhere. The only /system/lib/modules ko there was a "wlan.ko" which I'm sure is not what I'm looking for.. Any other ideas?? This is royally kicking my butt.. Bought the phone/VM service to give me an easy way to access several networks/servers I admin via OpenVPN w/o looking for a McD/Starbucks wifi and pulling out the laptop... Any other ideas??

Comment: In doing some further deep googling, I found what I thought might be what I was looking for, an ARM6/FroyoStock tun.ko... Quickly downloaded it, and was instantly disappointed, an insmod shows the following:

Comment: [47538.032379] tun: version magic '2.6.32.9 preempt mod_unload ARMv6 ' should be'2.6.32.9 mod_unload ARMv6 '

Comment: Hmm. It looks like the kernel compiled with your phone is not set up to be compiled with `PREEMPT`. If you can figure out where that file came from, you might be able to find the source and recompile it with the right flags.

Comment: Maybe try `/system/lib/modules/2.6.35.9-cyanogenmod/kernel/net/ipv4/tunnel4.ko`?

Comment: Just did that very thing.. copied it into /system/lib/modules/ and insmodded it... Gets  tun: version magic '2.6.35.9-cyanogenmod preempt mod_unload ARMv6 ' should be '2.6.32.9 mod_unload ARMv6 '

Comment: I downloaded the Froyo source for the Intercept from Samsung. Have been trying to figure out *how* to cross-compile that #$@%@#@#$ tun.ko myself... Do you know of any good tutorials on cross-compiling Android on Linux??? I'm about at my wits end..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this website: [Tun.ko Repository](http://droidvpn.com/tun-repository.php)

They got a long database of tun.ko for android phones. If you can see your phone model, kernel and build number on the list, Just download their app which lets you load the module from their database to your phone. After that you can then use a [vpn for your android](http://droidvpn.com/).